# ACTION_CALL is opening dialler on android 4.1 jelly bean

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a feature in my app which directly calls a phone number without going through the android dallier,
Everything worked fine on android 2.2 and 2.3,
but now since i upgraded my phone to 4.1,
The call intent being "ACTION_CALL" and **not** "ACTION_DIAL"
still goes to the dialer screen and waits for the user to tap the call button

Following is the block of code which is responsible to directly call a phone number:

```
void makeCall(Context context,String number){
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);  
 // Add the additional flags required for staring new Activity.
 callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
 context.startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

I also have the call permissions set in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Has anyone else faced a similar issue?

Comment: You cannot hold `CALL_PRIVILEGED`, unless you are part of the firmware. Beyond that, try getting rid of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. If neither of those help, comment back.

Comment: Heyy thanks for the comment, removing CALL_PRIVILEGED didnt help, and i need the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK as i start the call activity from background when no activity of my app is actually running.
But i realized that if the phone number being called is present in the phoneBook, call starts directly, if not the dialer opens up, that solves my problem, thanks :) (Probably a security feature since android 4.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems android treats "9999999991", "9999999992", "9999999993" since android 4.1 which i was using as dummy phone numbers for my testing, whereas the normal numbers dial up directly the above numbers are shown in the dialer.